# Best way to set custom path/ prefix in a aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Maybe it is duplicated of this question: [Write to a specific folder in S3 bucket using AWS Kinesis Firehose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50340543/174777). But maybe in the last year appeared new options.

I would like to know which is the best way to send incoming data streams to a specific path or prefix in an s3 bucket.

For instance, let's say that I have the following JSON object:

```
{"clientId":2,"event":"click","url":"http://www.url.com/foo"}
```

I would like to store it in a path like this:

```
s3Bucket/{event}/{clientId} => s3Bucket/click/2
```

I'm considering these options:

- Kinesis firehose: Maybe is it possible in some way to set a custom prefix like the example?
- lambda function: Trigger a lambda function with the incoming streams and set the custom prefix reading the JSON object.
- Other options ...

There's a better way to do that? Which of the above options is the best choice?

Comment: DO you want to store each JSON object in a separate Amazon S3 object, or do you want to combine them together into a smaller number of objects? I think the answers on the previous question are still valid.

Comment: I want to store the JSON objects in a separate Amazon S3 object. For instance, separate each object by `clientId`.

Comment: If you want to store each message in a separate Amazon S3 object, then why not simply write the data direct to S3? Whatever source you have will need to know how to send the data to Kinesis/Lambda, so instead just get it to store directly in S3 instead, using your desired prefix.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks.  I'll take a look

Comment: @JohnRotenstein what do you exotically mean? if i want to save in s3 with specific format i need to use kinesis stream and lambda to s3, i cant send from cloudwatch directly. or am i missing something?